# Delete a specific marker from the Google map before update the location

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to update the Location  of the marker in Google map which I am getting as response from the server. I am storing the Marker and the the `table_id` in a HashMap to track the marker in the map but with the current state a new marker is always being created in the `update the Location` without removing the old one. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

I have noticed it just works for the first update after it a new one is always being created.

**Code**

```
public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    GoogleMap map;
    Marker marker;
    HashMap<Integer, Marker> markerMap = new HashMap<Integer, Marker>();

        private void gotoLocation(int id, double lat, double lng,
                String route_direct) {

            final float zoom = 11;

            LatLng ll = null;

            if (markerMap.containsKey(id)) {
                // Update the location.
                marker = markerMap.get(id);
                marker.remove();

                ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                if (lat != 0 && lng != 0 && !route_direct.isEmpty()) {
                    MarkerOptions markerOpt = new MarkerOptions()
                            .title(route_direct).position(ll).visible(true);
                    marker = map.addMarker(markerOpt);
                    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll,
                            zoom);
                    map.moveCamera(update);
                }

            } else {

                ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                if (lat != 0 && lng != 0 && !route_direct.isEmpty()) {
                    MarkerOptions markerOpt = new MarkerOptions()
                            .title(route_direct).position(ll).visible(true);
                    marker = map.addMarker(markerOpt);
                    markerMap.put(id, marker);

                    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll,
                            zoom);
                    map.moveCamera(update);
                }

            }

        }
}
```

**Screenshot**
[image]

Comment: @DanielNugent: the id is the table_id from the table database. I cant unserstad why does it just work for the first update and then a new marker is being created!

Comment: I have debugged it before and it gets in the if Statement. I will try again and notify you.

Comment: @DanielNugent: I have tried it and the condition is being entered all the time but it is just working for the first update. Yes I have deleted the lines `getMapAsync` I placed them there for testing purposes. I have them in the `onCreate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running the code, I realized where the problem is.
In the case where the Marker already exists in the HashMap, you're not updating the entry in the HashMap with the new Marker reference.

So, in the case that it already exists, just remove the old Marker entry from the HashMap, and add the new Marker reference with the same key.

Just two lines of code added, with `//added` in the comments:

```
private void gotoLocation(int id, double lat, double lng,
                          String route_direct) {

    final float zoom = 11;

    LatLng ll = null;

    if (markerMap.containsKey(id)) {

        // Update the location.
        marker = markerMap.get(id);
        marker.remove();
        markerMap.remove(id); //added

        ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        if (lat != 0 && lng != 0 && !route_direct.isEmpty()) {
            MarkerOptions markerOpt = new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(route_direct).position(ll).visible(true);
            marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOpt);
            markerMap.put(id, marker); //added
            CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll,
                    zoom);
            mMap.moveCamera(update);
        }

    } else {

        ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        if (lat != 0 && lng != 0 && !route_direct.isEmpty()) {
            MarkerOptions markerOpt = new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(route_direct).position(ll).visible(true);
            marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOpt);
            markerMap.put(id, marker);

            CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll,
                    zoom);
            mMap.moveCamera(update);
        }

    }

}
```

Also, here is how I set up the simple test, just testing with one `id`, and updating it on each Map click:

```
  mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

            Log.d("MyMap", "MapClick");

            gotoLocation(1, point.latitude, point.longitude, "testing");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is there any explanation for this behaviour in the adding part (else block) when I add a new route to my bus table  with the same selected one, the new added route id is being recognized and the `else` block is being  entered afterward the marker is being added to the HashMap but is not being displayed on the map.

Comment: Additionally when the new Response reaches the method again I noticed that the last added marker with the new id is not in the HashMap and it just contains the elements of the first request also when the request is over and the new added  element stays in the HashMap for the request LifeCycle!